# How to make Tailwind table take up all horizontal space

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, tsx

I am having trouble making a table styled with Tailwind take up all the horizontal space in the parent div:
[image: Photo of table]

This is the code for the table in TSX.

```
<div className="flex flex-col grow w-max">
        <div className="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
          <div className="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="shadow overflow-x-auto border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg">
              <table className="table-fixed border-separate -sm:hidden empty-cells-hidden mx-auto my-auto">
                <thead className="rounded-tl rounded-tl bg-gray-200 uppercase">
                  <tr>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                    >
                      (column covered in red)
                    </th>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                    >
                      Date
                    </th>
                    <th
                      scope="col"
                      className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
                    >
                      Address
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody className="bg-white divide-gray-100 divide-y ">
                  {this.state.data
                    .map((t: any) => {
                      return {
                        strp: t.strpClaimed,
                        date: new Date(t.date).toLocaleDateString(),
                        address: t.address,
                      };
                    })
                    .map((e: any, i: number) => {
                      return (
                        <tr key={i} className="odd:bg-white even:bg-gray-100">
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            {e.strp}
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            {e.date}
                          </td>
                          <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                            <Link
                              href={`https://etherscan.io/address/${e.address}`}
                            >
                              <a className="underline-solid underline truncate">
                                {e.address.slice(0, 8) + "..."}
                              </a>
                            </Link>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      );
                    })}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have tried using flex and grow, but to no avail. The table is inside a parent div element, which that is inside a grid with two columns. No matter what I try, the table refuses to take up the blank horizontal space. Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use [`w-screen`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#viewport-width) to `table` class. It should work's properly in your case ;-)

```
<table className="table-fixed border-separate -sm:hidden empty-cells-hidden mx-auto my-auto w-screen">
```

---

Example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table class="table-auto border-separate border border-gray-400 w-screen">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="border border-gray-300">Song</th>
      <th class="border border-gray-300">Artist</th>
      <th class="border border-gray-300">Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="border border-gray-300">The Sliding Mr. Bones (Next Stop, Pottersville)</td>
      <td class="border border-gray-300">Malcolm Lockyer</td>
      <td class="border border-gray-300">1961</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border border-gray-300">Witchy Woman</td>
      <td class="border border-gray-300">The Eagles</td>
      <td class="border border-gray-300">1972</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="border border-gray-300">Shining Star</td>
      <td class="border border-gray-300">Earth, Wind, and Fire</td>
      <td class="border border-gray-300">1975</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yep, it works! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late response, but I was having a similar issue where the table was not filling up 100% of the parent div when results were empty.

What resolved my issue was adding the `w-full` class to my `<table>`.  When I attempted to add `w-screen`, the table broke through its container.

I wanted to post this in case anyone else needed this bit of info!